# Not able to get parent_item_id for cart items retrieved from Order - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.5, cart-items

I'm trying to get parent_item_id but it is returning null for all simple child products.

```
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
            $itemsData[] = [
                'name' => $item->getName(),
                'sku' => $item->getSku(),
                'quote_item_id' => $item->getQuoteItemId(),
                'parent_item_id' =>$item->getParentItemId(),
                'qty_ordered' => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
                'product_type' => $item->getProductType(),
                'weight' => $item->getWeight(),
                'price' => $item->getPrice()
            ];        
    }
```

I'm getting all item attributes in my $itemsData array except parent_item_id, though I've 4 children of a Bundle product and 1 child of a configurable product in Cart.

I'm doing it in `sales_order_place_before` observer. I tried `getAllItems()` and `getItems()` as well but no luck. Also confirmed from database, `parent_item_id` exists there for `quote_item_id`, but just not able to retrieve via getter method.

Answer (score 0):

I placed test order for two configurable items. When I use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()` I get the two parent rows returned, so I think parent_item_id will always be null.

[image]

If I use `$order->getItems()` I get four rows returned, each parent and each child.

[image]

But the parent_item_id is the parent row's item_id. I added `$item->getItemId()` to show the next row is linked to the row above. **It seems sku for the child is saved as sku for the parent**, so I'm not sure what your end goal is, but maybe you don't really need parent_item_id anyway. e.g. if you use this data later and need to load product repository, you should just use `get($sku)` method instead of `getById($productId)`.

[image]

My test code for the images:

```
$orderRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::class);
    $order = $orderRepositoryInterface->get(154);
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    
    foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo 'name: '. $item->getName() .'<br />';
                echo 'sku: ' . $item->getSku() .'<br />';
                echo 'order item_id: ' . $item->getItemId() . '<br />';
                echo 'quote_item_id: ' . $item->getQuoteItemId() .'<br />';
                echo 'parent_item_id: ' . $item->getParentItemId() .'<br />';
                echo 'product_id: ' . $item->getProductId() . '<br />';
                echo 'qty_ordered: ' . $item->getQtyOrdered() .'<br />';
                echo 'product_type: ' . $item->getProductType() .'<br />';
                echo 'weight: ' . $item->getWeight() .'<br />';
                echo 'price: ' . $item->getPrice() .'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: for me both $order->getAllVisibleItems() and $order->getItems() are showing the same number of items, all four if we consider your example.

Can you please show your code? Also which Magento version you're using?

Comment: My end goal is to get the same output as you've mentioned in your first example of $order->getAllVisibleItems(). But for me, I'm getting all four items, both parent and child.

Comment: Maybe because it is sales_order_place_before? There is also sales_order_place_after you could try. In those I just used your code but not in observer (just changed output to echo instead of an array), I loaded the order by repository. So, maybe you should try: $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getEntityId();  and then load order repository by $orderId

Comment: I tried sales_order_place_after as well but no luck. I think the issue is with $order object only, even $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getEntityId(); is also returning nothing in sales_order_save_before/after.        Solution: From $order, I get the $quote as $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId()); and the I'm getting correct data in getAllVisivleItems(). So I'm using it now.